# Make an array accessible to any subunit included using #include "unit.c"?

Tags: c, global-variables

How do I make sure a function from unit.c called from my main.c that needs an array declared in main.c functions properly?

Is there any way to declare variables globally across .c files? Is there a smart way to do it without using global variables?

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sub.c"

int main(void)
{
    int matrix[5][5];
    matrix[5][1] = 5;
    Range();
}
```

Now for sub.c:

```
int Range()
{
    printf("Your Range is: %i",Matrix[5][1])
}
```

Now the problem occuring is that now upon compiling there will be errors saying that

```
"In file included from main.c:
"sub.c:3:15: Error: Matrix not declared"
```

Or something along those lines.

Comment: Can you give an example (even if it won't compile) of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Sure, I'll update the question.

Comment: Still, good programming practices are to pass it as parameter.

Comment: If I do decide to pass it as a parameter, how would I pass an array? Could I pass Matrix1 to the program and inside the program assign a Matrix2 to the Matrix1 somehow? I would need to alter Matrix1 after the function is done.

Comment: Just pass the address of the array as param

Comment: forgotten a semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

So, several things:

1. Don't `#include` .c files (that is, source code); this is a bad habit to get into.  For a small, simple program like this it's not a big deal, but as your programs become bigger and more complex, it will cause build and maintenance headaches.  What you want to do instead is define a header file that only includes the *declaration* of your function, rather than the *definition* (body) of it, something like the following:

   ```
   /**
    * sub.h - declaration for Range function
    */
   #ifndef SUB_H  // include guards; prevents this file from being processed 
   #define SUB_H  // more than once for the same translation unit

   /**
    * Changing the type of Range to void since you aren't returning anything, and you 
    * aren't using the result of the function in your main function
    */
   void Range( /* parameter declarations, which we'll get into below */ ); 

   #endif
   ```

   You'd then `#include` this file as

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include "sub.h"

   int main( void )
   {
     int Matrix[5][5];
     Matrix[5][1] = 5; // this is an error; your array dimensions only go from 0 to 4
     Range( /* parameters, including Matrix, which we'll get into below */ );
   }
   ```

   and compile your `sub.c` separately and link the resulting object files together.
2. Don't use global variables if you can help it; ideally, functions and their callers should communicate exclusively through parameters, return values, and exceptions (in languages which support exceptions, anyway, which C doesn't).  You should pass `Matrix` as a parameter to your `Range` function, along with parameters for the array's size, and any additional information required by the function to do its job.  Since you want to print the value of a single element, you should pass the row and column number of that element as well.

   Now, here's where things get headachy - C's treatment of array expressions is a little non-intuitive.  Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

   If you pass the array as a parameter like so:

   ```
   Range(Matrix);
   ```

   then type of the *expression* `Matrix` is "5-element array of 5-element array of `int`".  Since this expression is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it is converted to an expression of type "pointer to 5-element array of `int`", and the value is the address of the first row of the array (which is the same as the address of the array itself).  That means your `Range` function would be declared as something like

   ```
   void Range( int m[][5] )
   ```

   or

   ```
   void Range( int (*m)[5] )
   ```

   (the parentheses in the second declaration matter; without them, `m` would be declared as an array of pointers to `int`, which is not what we want).
   In the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[]` and `T a[N]` are both interpreted as `T *a`; that is, `a` is declared as a pointer to `T`, not an array of `T`.

   Note that, since you passed the address of the array to the function, any changes the function makes to the array will be reflected in the caller; that is, if `Range` changes the value of `m[4][0]`, you'll see that changed value in `Matrix[4][0]`.
3. Since we only specify the number of columns in the declaration for `m`, we want to pass an additional parameter specifying the number of rows.  C doesn't do any bounds checking on array accesses, meaning you can write something like

   ```
   x = m[20][1];
   ```

   without getting a warning at compile time or guaranteeing a crash at runtime.  So you need to do that bounds checking yourself, meaning you need to know how many rows the array has, in addition to the number of columns.  You would pass a separate parameter for the number of rows:

   ```
   code>Range(Matrix, 5);
   ```

   meaning your function declaration would look something like

   ```
   void Range(int m[][5], size_t rows);
   ```
4. One flaw with the above approach is that the number of columns in `m` is fixed at 5; this function won't be able to work on matrices of other sizes.  If you're 
   working with a compiler that supports *variable-length arrays*<sup>1</sup>, you can use a variable to specify the array dimensions, rather than a compile-time constant.  Since the variable needs to be declared before it can be used in an array declaration, you'd have to write the prototype as

   ```
   void Range( size_t rows, size_t cols, int m[][cols] );
   ```

   and call the function as

   ```
   Range(5, 5, Matrix);
   ```

   This will allow you to use the `Range` function on matrices of different sizes, such as:

   ```
   int M1[5][5]; 
   int M2[9][9];
   int M3[20][20];
   ...
   Range(5, 5, M1);
   Range(9, 9, M2);
   Range(20, 20, M3);
   ```

   Now, if you only intend for this function to work with 5x5 matrices, then hardcoding the dimension isn't a problem; it's only an issue if you intend to use this function for any sized matrix.
5. If you are using a compiler that doesn't support VLAs, you'll need a different approach.  Instead of passing the array expression as a parameter, we pass a pointer to the first element of the array.  We'll treat this pointer as though it were a 1-d array instead of a 2-d array, like so:

   ```
   void Range( int *m, size_t rows, size_t cols )
   {
     printf("Your range is: %d\n", m[4 * cols + 1]);
   }
   ```

   and you would call it as

   ```
   Range(&Matrix[0][0], 5, 5);
   ```
6. You're assuming the presence of an element at `Matrix[5][1]`; however, arrays in C are 0-origin, meaning that both dimensions are indexed from 0 to 4.  So to access the 1st element of the 5th row, you'd refer to `Matrix[4][0]`.  `Matrix[5][1]` is outside the bounds of your array.  

   This also brings up the question of whether you're ever going to want to check an element other than `m[4][0]`.  If you want the function to access any arbitrary element of the array, you will want to pass the row and column number as separate parameters; this, combined with passing the array's dimensions as parameters, gives you a way to make sure you aren't trying to access an element outside of the array's bounds.  So, your `Range` function would look something like

   ```
   void Range(int m[][5] size_t rows, size_t i, size_t j)
   {
     if ( i < rows && j < 5 )
       printf("Your range is: %d\n", m[i][j];
   }
   ```

   and you would call it as

   ```
   Range(Matrix, 5, 4, 0);
   ```
7. Which brings us to our last item (finally); don't use "magic numbers" in your code. Instead of splashing the literal `5` all over the place, define *symbolic constants* (preprocessor macros) to represent the number of rows and columns in your matrix.  For one thing, if you decide to change the array dimensions, you only need to update the constant definitions, rather than chase down every occurrence of the literal `5` and determining whether it's being used to check your array access.  Putting all of the above together (and assuming you're okay with `Range` only working with arrays of a specific size), we get:

   ```
   /**
    * sub.h - declaration for Range function
    */
   #ifndef SUB_H  // include guards; prevents this file from being processed 
   #define SUB_H  // more than once for the same translation unit

   /**
    * Since these macros are going to be used by both the main function
    * and the Range function, it makes sense to define them in the
    * sub.h file, as it will be included in both main.c and sub.c
    */
   #define ROWS 5
   #define COLS 5

   /**
    * Prints the value at index i,j of m; if i or j are out of
    * range, prints nothing.
    */
   void Range( int m[][COLS], size_t rows, size_t i, size_t j ); 

   #endif
   ```

   ```
   /**
    * sub.c - implementation of Range function
    */
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include "sub.h" 

   void Range( int m[][COLS], size_t rows, size_t i, size_t j )
   {
     if ( i < rows && j < COLS )
       printf("Your range is: %d\n", m[i][j]);
   }
   ```

   ```
   /**
    * main.c
    */
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include "sub.h"

   int main( void )
   {
     int Matrix[ROWS][COLS];
     Matrix[4][0] = 5;             // assumes we know 4 and 0 are within
     Range( Matrix, ROWS, 4, 0 );  // the array bounds.
   }
   ```

So, are you *thoroughly* confused yet?

---

<sup>1. A C99 compiler, or a C2011 compiler where the macro __STDC_NO_VLA__ is either undefined or 0.  Some C89 compilers may support VLAs as an extension.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Good programming practices dictate to use them as parameters, so the option'd be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sub.h"

    int main(void)
    {
        int matrix[5][5];
        matrix[5][1] = 5;
        Range(matrix);
    }
```

Where sub.h includes only the prototype of the funcion.

Now for sub.c:

```
int Range(int matrix[][5])
{
    printf("Your Range is: %i",matrix[5][1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if I require the matrix file from main.c to be altered?

Comment: You're passing it here as a pointer to the matrix, so, everything you modify on Range() will be "sent back" to main

Comment: Is it on purpose, that you wrote Range(int matrix[][5]), leaving the first dimension on the array open?

Comment: When passing a matrix as parameter you can omit the first dimension, so the matrix[][5] is on purpose.

Comment: You wrote Matrix with a capital M, it throws out "undeclared!" compiling errors when I try, what did I miss?

Comment: sorry, was a copy of your code above, it's matrix with lower like the one in int Range(int matrix[][5])

Answer (score 0):

You should have a header file which have the prototype of the function you need to call and include it. I don't think you include the .c file

You also need to pass parameter to the function.

If you need to access variables across files, you need to use extern variable.